# Last element of the ruby array is nil

Tags: ruby

I have a simple ruby program that has 2 steps so far
1. Ask the user for the number of stock market symbols they want to track
2. Ask the user to input these symbols

```
puts("How many stocks do you want to track ?")
numStocks = gets.chomp()
puts("Please enter #{numStocks} stock symbols: ")

array = Array.new(numStocks.to_i)
for i in 1..numStocks.to_i do 
    array.insert(i-1, gets.chomp())
end

puts("Stock symbols entered ... #{array}")
```

The output that is printed onto the console is 
`Stock symbols entered ... ["aapl", nil]`

Why is the last element of the array `nil` in this case and what's the proper way to get rid of it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Array.new` creates a new array, filling it with the quantity of elements you specified. `Array.new(3)` is the same as `[nil, nil, nil]`. `Array.new(2, 'a')` is the same as `['a', 'a']`.

You then use `array.insert` which adds instead of replaces the elements. You could use `array[i-1] = gets.chomp()` to set the values, but there's really no reason to initialize the array this way at all.

A "more Ruby" way to write this all would be:

```
puts 'How many stocks do you want to track ?'
num_stocks = gets.chomp
puts "Please enter #{num_stocks} stock symbols: "

array = 1.upto(num_stocks.to_i).map do
  gets.chomp
end

puts "Stock symbols entered ... #{array}"
```

EDIT:
Also, it’s worth mentioning that in Ruby, arrays are not a fixed size. You can add and remove elements from them as you please. If I had to guess, you’re used to languages like C, where you have to define the size of your array up front and then it’s just that size forever (that’s what I’m guessing you were trying to do anyways).

And another thing, in Ruby it’s not very common to use `Array.new`. Most times people just define an array by typing an array literal.

```
array = [1,2,3]
```

A ruby array is more like a List in other languages. It supports `push` (though `<<` is a more common method for adding to an array), `pop`, and other list-like features.

Comment: I just updated my answer with a little more info as well. Glad I could help!

Comment: `Array.new(num_stocks.to_i) { gets.chomp }` would also work.

Comment: As a note this statement is untrue *"Array.new(2, 'a') is the same as ['a', 'a']."*. In `Array.new(2, 'a')` both elements in the `Array` are the same object as proven by `b = Array.new(2, 'a'); b[1] << 'h'; b #=> ["ah","ah"]`; however in `['a','a']` each element is a distinct object that simply happens to have a equal value and representation, and thus `b = ['a','a']; b[1] << 'h'; b #=> ["a", "ah"]`

Comment: That’s an excellent point @engineersmnky. I’m so used to frozen string literals nowadays. (Rubocop never lets me forget the magic comment.)

Comment: @Nate literal strings is merely a simple example as opposed to `Array.new(4, MyObject.new)` or even `Array.new(4,String.new('a'))`

Comment: Right. Point being, Array.new passes the same object instance into all indices, where a literal would be separate instances unless I used a variable. Such as `val = 'a'; array = [val, val]`

Answer (score 2):

Thats because when you do `Array.new(numStocks.to_i)` it initializes an array with 3 nil values and you keep adding on to it,

the proper way to get rid of `nil` from array is to use `.compact` on the array but I suggest you change your logic,

maybe something like this

```
puts("How many stocks do you want to track ?")
numStocks = gets.chomp()
puts("Please enter #{numStocks} stock symbols: ")

array = Array.new() # or array = []
numStocks.to_i.times do
  array << gets.chomp()
end

puts("Stock symbols entered ... #{array}")
```

or you could ask the user to enter the comma separated symbols, so you don't have to loop, and split them,

```
puts("Please enter #{numStocks} stock symbols separated by commas (a,b): ")
symbols = gets.chomp().split(',')
puts("Stock symbols entered ... #{array}")
```